# Prevent React from rendering inline styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, inline-styles, css-in-js

```
const Component = () => <CustomButton color="highlight">Click me</CustomButton>;

const colors = { highlight: "#123456" };

export const CustomButton = styled(Button)`
    ${({ props }) => 
        color: ${colors[props.color]}};
`;
```

How can I prevent React form rendering "color="highlight" as an inline style in line 1?

I sometimes use CSS named properties to use them within my CSS in JS library as props (styled components in this case).

React renders this HTML, though:
[image]

`color="highlight"` is not valid HTML and displays no color.

Since `color="highlight` is rendered as an inline style, my styled components stylesheets are not working anymore and the styles are broken.

The correct output should be

```
// no inline styles applied
<button class="sc-crzoAe dV0xyD sc-cTJkRt jDcPXG" />

// corresponding style sheet class
.sc-crzoAe { 
  color: #123456;
}
```

Keep in mind that React handles some CSS properties like `width`, `height` as a shortcut to `style={{ width: "100%", height: "50%" }}`. That's where the behaviour comes from I think.

One idea I had was to just rename the prop, but it would be nice to have a prop called `color` to take care of the color.

Comment: Button is another custom class?

Comment: @Apostolos `Button` is a another custom component, yes. But I think it doesn't matter. The behaviour would be the same if it is styled(button).

Comment: yes, it doesnt matter, correct. check the answer. i created a sandobx with similiar senario

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to set color is this:

```
export const CustomButton = styled(Button)`
    color: => ${(props) => colors[props.color]}; 
`
```

An example can be shown [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-demo-forked-x4jc6)

Comment: Your codepen also renders "color=highlight" if you check the dom tree. `<button color="highlight" class="sc-gsTCUz sc-dlfnbm kSuqIw ckOqvP">Hello 2</button>`. This causes unreliable bugs in my application.

Comment: if you use another property? instead of color e.g. colProp?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that. But I don't like that solution and I'm curious if there is another way.

Comment: I don't think you can "remove" somehow the class property since it is declared in your tag. that's why i asked at first place about button and Button.

Comment: at my example though the color is changed. what is your exact problem?

Comment: For me, sometimes the color changes, sometimes not. It is unreliable in my application.